# Javascript Slider with Click buttons to show content

Tags: javascript, slider, scroller

Trying to create a custom javascript slider, the idea is it cycles through 4 divs each with their own different content automatically. In addition, at the side there is a button for each, when you click it, it will show the relevant div and stop on it.

However there are currently three errors with this
1. Once you have clicked on an item, after a while, it continues to loop
2. Once you try and click another item, it will not.
3. The longer you stop on the page, the faster it cycles through the items.

Any help is appreciated, thankyou!

http://jsfiddle.net/Ek5pQ/

Comment: Please reduce your problem code and put it in the question instead of a link to JSfiddle.

Comment: But, general advice by looking at your code is to *let the loop run forever by rescheduling itself*.  Don't stop and start it - you are not careful enough about that for it to work.  Control the loop with flags instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deestan is right, run a continuous loop. You were creating new timers indiscriminately, which must of been creating the speedups. Here is a simplified version of your code (http://jsfiddle.net/Ek5pQ/45/):

```
//the variables
var i = 1;
var myTimer;

function myLoop() {
    //hide everything
    $(".nHstuff").hide();
    $(".nH").removeClass("active");
    //show just the stuff we want
    $("#nHstuff" + i).show();
    $("#nH" + i).addClass("active");
    //increment variables
    i++;

    if (i === 5) {
        i = 1;
    }

    //the timer      
    myTimer = setTimeout(myLoop, 3000);
}
//start the loop
myLoop();

//what to do if hovered over an item
$(".nH").hover(function() {
    clearTimeout(myTimer);
    // clear content
    $(".nHstuff").hide();
    $(".nH").removeClass("active");
    // show content
    $("#nHstuff" + (this.id.substr(this.id.length - 1))).show();
});

$(".nH").mouseout(function() {
    myLoop();
});

$(".nH").click(function() {
    clearTimeout(myTimer);
    i = this.id.substr(this.id.length - 1, 1);
    //show just the stuff we want
    $("#nHstuff" + i).show();
    $("#nH" + i).addClass("active");
    // To start looping again, call myLoop
});
```

Comment: Quick question, the hover and click function on this isn't working in my website despite working in jsfiddle, what could be the cause?